How can I prevent nginx from responding 304 to php page requests?
Initial data: there is a web server with nginx version 1.18.0 as the frontend and php-fpm version 7.4 as the backend. I need absolutely all requests for php pages to be transferred from nginx to php-fpm. Nginx caching is disabled. But when I look at the logs, I see that sometimes Nginx responds to requests from Google robots with 304, not 200, and the response length is zero. How to prevent nginx from doing this?
The nginx configuration in a simplified form looks like this:
location ~ \.php$ {
  limit_req zone=zone_page_php burst=20;
  expires -1;
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

I've already dug through half the Internet, but I still can't understand why this is happening? How can nginx know that the page has not changed without passing the request to php-fpm and receiving the page from it?

I solved this problem myself. First, I created a copy of a working web server to experiment with. For debugging, I enabled the debug option in the error log - this allowed me to see information about traffic between nginx and php-fpm. Then I sent this request to this server:
curl --header "If-Modified-Since: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT" -kv "https://myserver.copy/"

and received the following headers in response from the server:
< HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 06 May 2024 13:42:55 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=9icgi1iemao0s3mqu721uhcube; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache

Then I looked at the error log and saw in it that nginx, as it should, forwards the request to php-fpm, and php-fpm responds with “304 Not Modified”. That is, it turned out that the problem was not with nginx, but with php-fpm. And I was able to solve this problem by adding the following line to location:
fastcgi_param HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE "";

